# Как из header получить filename при получение файла из другого сервера на свой

Tags: php, curl

Здравствуйте! С помощью curl получаю header файла, который лежит по этой пути http://zakupki.gov.ru/223/purchase/public/download/download.html?id=3324768 . Теперь мне нужно из header получить имя файла либо расширения файла. Header имеет такой вид

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 24 May 2015 12:42:09 GMT
Content-Type: application/download
Content-Length: 648192
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: route223p7=0; Domain=zakupki.gov.ru; Path=/223
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%2070-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B7%D0%BF.doc"; filename*=UTF-8''%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%2070-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B7%D0%BF.doc
Content-Language: en-US
Expires: Sun, 24 May 2015 12:57:09 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Cache-Control: public
```

Как мне получить значение filename, либо .doc.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: По вашей ссылке 404.

Comment: Вытащить из заголовка content-disposition

Comment: При переходе по ссылке начинает скачиваться файл.

Comment: Как вытащить из заголовка content-disposition?

Comment: `if (preg_match('~Content-Disposition\:\h*attachment\;\h*filename=\"\K[^\"]+~i', $header, $match)) echo urldecode($match[0]);`

Comment: Вообще, для разбора получаемых заголовков уже давно имеется нативная функция `get_headers`. Но если вам по кайфу конструировать велосипеды - то вперед.

Comment: @Deadooshka
`$ch=curl_init();  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0');  $header = curl_exec($ch);  if(preg_match('~Content-Disposition\:\h*attachment\;\h*filename=\"\K[^\"]+~i', $header, $match)){  echo urldecode($match[0]);  }  curl_close ($ch);`  Вы имеете ввиду вот так? Так не работает.

Comment: @u_mulder `get_headers` возвращает 404 not found

Comment: вроде нужно CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER ещё, чтобы возвращало...

Comment: @Deadooshka  Большое спасибо Вам, получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Подсказка @Deadooshka мне очень помог, спасибо его.

```html
<?php
  $ch=curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0');

  $header = curl_exec($ch);
  if(preg_match('~Content-Disposition\:\h*attachment\;\h*filename=\"\K[^\"]+~i',$header,$match)){
    $fileName = urldecode($match[0]);
    echo $fileName;
  }
    curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

Код четко работает.

Answer (score 0):

$curl_output; // Полученная строка от си-урла

$result = array(); // Массив найденых результатов

preg_match('/filename="([ABCDEFabcdef0-9\%-]{0,}.[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,})"/',$curl_output ,$result);

$result[1];//  название файла с расширением

Comment: preg_match - это функция которая ищет подстроки при помощи регулярных выражений